# Safari on iOS randomly duplicates button style from the next button

Tags: ios, css, reactjs, safari, mobile-safari

I have a page where I ask my user to take a picture with their camera. Then I show the picture and ask if they want to retake it, or confirm the photo. There should be two buttons with different styles, however sometimes safari shows [two identical buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsHmy.png). It seems as second button is shown on top of the first one and separately below, but nonetheless they both function as expected.

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZYEx.png)

The platform is written on react and the screen where the photo should be taken has [one button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15yw1.png), which is Primary.

I also tried giving the buttons different ids to avoid safari reusing primary button in the second screen for both elements, but that did not help.

```html
<button class="Button_primary__I_6B6 Button_highlighted__xVkxB Button_base__Cb726" style="background-color: rgb(73, 197, 182);">Take photo</button>
```

Here is what I get:

```html
<button class="Button_secondary__1goL3 Button_highlighted__xVkxB Button_base__Cb726" style="border-color: rgb(73, 197, 182); color: rgb(73, 197, 182);">Retake photo</button>
<button class="Button_primary__I_6B6 Button_highlighted__xVkxB Button_base__Cb726" style="background-color: rgb(73, 197, 182);">Confirm</button>
```

I tried removing some css properties, or adding -webkit-appearance, but it seems that the issue is somewhere else as sometimes it displays correct view and sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with CSS property filter:

```css
.base { 
  filter: brightness(1);

  &:hover {
    filter: brightness(1.15);
  }
}
```

css filter is slow on safari and for mobile devices when the screen rotates, or DOM changes it can cause a bug. Issue was solved by removing filter property for touchscreen devices for my class since hover is not a necessity for them:

```css
.base {

...

  @media (pointer: coarse) {
    filter: none;

    &:hover {
      filter: none;
    }
  }
}
```